# Jquery autocomplete _renderItem is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

_renderItem is not executing at all, tried with console.log too no messages printed. Tried with 'autocomplete', 'ui-autocomplete', 'Autocomplete' attributes no hope.

In addition I could not understand the purpose of "response with map functions", so disabled it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

myVars.shId = $('#dataVar').attr('sh-data');

///// search ////// http://jsbin.com/xavatajiku/edit?js,output
console.log(myVars.shId);
$('#name-list').autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: myVars.czbUrl,
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10, shopId: myVars.shId },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    /*response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        console.log(data);
                        return {

                            value: item.product_name,
                            avatar: item.pfimage_thumb,
                            rep: item.product_name,
                            selectedId: item.url
                        };
                    }))*/
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {

                             alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label)
                                                      : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

            return false;
        }
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        console.log('test');
        /*var inner_html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.pfimage_thumb + '"></div><div class="label"><h3> Reputation:  ' + item.volume + '</h3></div><div class="description">' + item.product_name + '</div></div></a><hr/>';
        return $("<li></li>")
                .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                .append(inner_html)
                .appendTo(ul);*/
    };
```

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<h4>search:<input type="text" id="name-list" /></h4>
```

Comment: putting your `jquery-ui.js` after `jquery.min.js` and check if any errors in console

Comment: Yes it is like that, I misplaced it here., it is now corrected.

Comment: What does your `data` look like? Have you checked it's being delivered as expected? Most likely the `renderMenu` function is not firing because the `response()` callback receives nothing

Comment: I can see my the data in console.log(data) at success function, Is the response blocking renderItem?, If I enable response I get error like 'item.product_name is null, etc.

Comment: Got below error with response function enabled.  "main.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_name' of null"

Answer (score 11):

A few small corrections and you should be on your way:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gm3sfem/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var myData = [{
    product_name: "Name 1",
    pfimage_thumb: "thumb1.jpg",
    url: "url1"
  }, {
    product_name: "Name 2",
    pfimage_thumb: "thumb2.jpg",
    url: "url2"
  }, {
    product_name: "Name 3",
    pfimage_thumb: "thumb3.jpg",
    url: "url3"
  }];
  $('#name-list').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify(myData)
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          response(data);
        }
      })
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      return false;
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log('test');
    var item = $('<div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.pfimage_thumb + '"></div><div class="label"><h3> Reputation:  ' + item.volume + '</h3></div><div class="description">' + item.product_name + '</div></div>')
    return $("<li>").append(item).appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

If your data is coming back, pass it to `response()` to ensure that the menmu get rendered. You do not need `<a>` since `select` will be fired either way.

Comment: Thanks Twisty, I will make this changes and see. One more thing, I dont want to close the dropdown post selection of the item. It should stay there to select the next option. my selection means clicking addcart button, so selecting multiple should be enabled.

Comment: Then select should return false to help keep menu open. Or consider: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: The jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gm3sfem/ is no longer an example of this.

Answer (score 5):

i wanted to set _renderItem and _renderMenu, so i came across the following example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var products = $(".products").clone();
        $('#search-box').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../ajax-search.php",
                    dataType:"json",
                    html: true,
                    data:{term:request.term},
                    success: function(data){
                        response(data.slice(0,5));
                    }
                });
            },
            create: function (event,ui){
               $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .append("<img src=../images/"+item.Image +" alt='img' />")
                    .append('<a>' + item.Number  + '<br>' + item.Name  + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
               $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderMenu = function () {
                    this.menu.element.css({
                    width: $('#search-box').width(),
                    border: 'medium solid'
                });

            };
        }
        });
```

if found this answer [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/renderitem-for-jquery-autocomplete-doesn%C2%B4t-work-undefined)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Jquery widget factory to extend autocomplete object. It is explained in these articles:

https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

it worked like this:

you add your widget code like this:

```
$.widget(
"custom.superAuto",
$.ui.autocomplete,
{
    _renderMenu : function(ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        ul.append("<div><span style='float:left; width: 50%; border-top:none; color:#949494;font-family:arial;font-size:14px' id='products'>KOSSSS</span></div>");
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        self._renderItem(ul.find("#products"),item);
        });
    },
    _renderItem: function (column, item)
    {
        return $("<li style='text-align:left; font-size:12px; height:28px'>")
    }
});
```

The above code extends autocomplete object and you can use superAuto instead and use your custom logic to render your menu like this:

```
$(".suggestion-input").superAuto(
                {
                    minLength : 2,
                    source : function(request, response) {

                        $.get(encodeURI("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/search/" + request.term),
                                function(data) {
                                    response(data);
                                });

                    }
                    
                });
```

Comment: I don't think you can do things like triggering the autocomplete manually via this method though. i.e. via $('.suggestion-input').autocomplete('search');

Comment: you are right, you cannot. You need to use the newly created widget instead, which is 'superAuto'. like $('.suggestion-input').superAuto('search')